# Error in creating Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, build-error

I am using NetBeans ID 8.0.1 to generate a javadoc, but whenever i try to create javadoc following error occurs:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
1 error
D:\EFConnect\libs\activemq-all-5.9.1.jar(org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnection.java):107: error: cannot access Logger
import org.slf4j.Logger;
                ^
  bad source file: D:\EFConnect\libs\activemq-all-5.9.1.jar(org/slf4j/Logger.java)
    file does not contain class org.slf4j.Logger
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
D:\EFConnect\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1208: Javadoc returned 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

My project otherwise is working fine, also the classes mentioned in the error also exist where they are supposed to exist.

Comment: slf4j is missing, according to that error. Try re-downloading active-mq-all-5.9.1.jar & clean your project in NetBeans. According to GrepCode, Logger is present in the activemq-all jar, so I suspect you have an incomplete/corrupted jar and/or build cache.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion, i have tried this, still the same result.

Comment: How are you constructing the javadoc?

Comment: Right click on my project in Netbeans and then select Generate Javadoc option.